# How to read and modify csv files in function in loop and save as separated DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I try to create function in Python Pandas where:

1. I read 5 csv
2. make some aggregations on each readed csv (just to make it easier, we can delete one column)
3. save each modified csv as DataFrames

Currently I have something like below, nevertheless it return only one DataFrame as output not 5, how can I change below code ?

```
def xx():
    #1. read 5 csv 
    for el in [col for col in os.listdir("mypath") if col.endswith(".csv")]:
    df = pd.read_csv("path/f"{el}"")
    
    #2. making aggregations
    df = df.drop("COL1", axis=1)

    #3. saving each modified csv to separated DataFrames
     ?????
```

FInally I need to have 5 separated DataFrames after modifications, how can I modify my function to achieve taht in Phython Pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty dictionnary and feed it gradually with the five processed dataframes.

Try this:

```
def xx():
    dico_dfs={}

    for el in [file for file in os.listdir("mypath") if file.endswith(".csv")]:
        #1. read 5 csv 
        df = pd.read_csv(f"path/{el}")

        #2. making aggregations
        df = df.drop("COL1", axis=1)

        #3. saving each modified csv to separated DataFrames
        dico_dfs[el]= df
```

You can access to each dataframe by using the filename as a key, e.g `dico_dfs["file1.csv"]`.

If needed, you can make a single dataframe by using [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) : `pd.concat(dico_dfs)`.

Comment: abokey, where should I eventually implement pd.concat(dico_dfs) if I would like to have signle DF ?

Comment: As said in the line before, you can use `dico_dfs["file1.csv"]` to access to each single dataframe.